# Training custom form, selectionMark bounding box identification issues

Tags: azure, preview, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I'm using the current preview version of FOTT while working on training a custom form. I've noticed that the ability of the analyze layout has issues identifying selection marks in some cases. I'm training a model to use with a standard US govt form (MCSA-5876) so we have no ability to change the form layout. The images are being uploaded as jpg, which is a requirement of this project.

1. Checkboxes (square) seem to be identified fine
2. Radio options work the majority of time if the option is unchecked & the image isn't distorted at all
3. Radios that are hand written filled in using an X thru it works majority of the time
4. Radios that come from a filled in PDF that have a dot in the middle will fail more often than not. Note that these are being sent in to us as a jpg not pdf.

I tried doing analysis on some filled in PDF files for testing, but the results for those are even worse than the jpg as far as the selectionMarks go.  I have also tried creating my own mocked up forms & saved as a high resolution jpg, but they experience similar results as the customer ones.

What I'm looking for are suggestions on how to improve the accuracy of the selectionMark. I'm currently working on setting up a training set for the model greater than 20 images. I'm also wondering if there is a way to modify the initial analysis and specify the bounding boxes for the selections. Would hand editing the *.ocr.json files in the blob storage work? Definitely not the ideal solution though.

I've attached an image showing the issue I'm running in to. Radios like MD, DO, Physician Assistant, etc. do not have bounding boxes. Others like Advanced Practice Nurse and Other Practitioner do. If the analyzer can't find them for tagging, it will not find them when you analyze a new document using the trained model. Thus the value returns as null.

TIA
Rich

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMIUJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest Form Recognizer release 2.1-preview.3 API ? We are continuously improving our extraction quality. I tried the sample form and both checkboxes and radio buttons were extracted. Can you please share some samples where you saw misses (please anonymize data) you can also reach out to Form Recognizer Contact us formrecog_contact@microsoft.com or open a support ticket and we can assist.

Used the latest FR try out tool - https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net/layout-analyze highlighted text extracted and selection marks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk7yz.jpg

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, we are using the latest preview release. I will put together some samples and send those off ASAP.

- Rich